# How to convert GridFSFile to java.io.File

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongo-java-driver

I am using spring-data-mongodb version 2.1.5 and mongo-java-driver version 3.10.1. I need to parse a file to extract keywords. In order to do that I loaded file from db using `com.mongodb.client.gridfs.model.GridFSFile`, but I can't find any functions to convert this to java.io.File. Also I have a doubt in mongo-java-driver, what is the actual difference between  `com.mongodb.client.gridfs.model.GridFSFile` and `com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFSFile`?

Comment: why do you need to convert to java.io.File?

Comment: to extract keywords from a file content.

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to get File using GridFsResource. Used GridFsResource.getInputStream() and convert it to File using FileUtils.